# Why can the using directive not be used recursively in c#?

Tags: c#, using-directives

Why cannot the using directive be used recursively in c#?

```
using MyKey = System.String;
using MyValue = System.Int32;
using AllowedPair = System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String, System.Int32>;
using NotAllowedPair = System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<MyKey, MyValue>;  //CS0246
```

I felt it was reasonable to want to build up using statements in this way so I am curious why I am not allowed to.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question for someone who was in the room when this feature was created.

Comment: Perhaps you could try asking [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime).

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, I disagree.  There are several reasons why it could be this way:
  1) Its impossible for the compiler to implement (I doubt)
  2) Its an esoteric feature not worth implementing (I doubt) 
  3) If implemented it would allow the user to shoot themselves in the foot in some way (I presume this to be the case).

Comment: I doubt it's impossible for the compiler. That leaves three options: 1) Microsoft didn't feel implementing it was worth the cost of ding so. 2) Microsoft couldn't implement it because they felt like it would cause a problem elsewhere. 3) Microsoft didn't consider this use case.  Perhaps there's a 4th option that they felt it might be confusing. -- You would have to ask Microsoft why it's not implemented.

Comment: IMO the most plausible explanation is that (almost) noone cares about this feature. Because aliases are less useful than generics and interfaces, they cease to exist after compilation.

Comment: I just wanted to add that the reason I voted to close the question is because [so] requires that questions be objectively answerable. Here the answer seems to be "it could exist, but doesn't" and unless we get really lucky with who answers, any possible answer as to why it doesn't would be speculation and thus not objective. That's my perspective anyway.

Comment: Remember, every feature starts off with [Minus 100 points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericgu/minus-100-points). It's not that you're "not allowed", it's that nobody has provided sufficiently compelling reasons why *this feature* should be developed ahead of many others.

Comment: Btw this is definitely possible to implement. Other languages (e.g. C++) already have it. Moreover, technically this isn't even recursion, just a simple substitution. I'm not sure why OP refers to it as recursion.